# Trayicon transparency background + JavaFX + Linux? its possible?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, javafx, transparency, trayicon

Does anyone know if JavaFX already have support background transparency in trayicon in linux OS?
I tried this solution in a long time and not found.

thank you

**I've tried with svg format and no success.